# Is it possible to express any quadratic fermionic system in terms of a quadratic majorana system and viceversa?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fermions, majorana-fermions

Can one always write, for some suitable matrix $M$
$$
H= \sum^N_{jk}(A_{jk}c^\dagger_jc_k+B_{jk}c_jc_k+h.c.)=i\sum^{2N}_{jk} M_{jk} \gamma_j\gamma_k,
$$
for **any** $A,B$? And viceversa, can one always find $A,B$ for **any** $M$? Where $c_j$ are fermionic operators and $\gamma_j$ are Majorana operators. Where $A$ needs to be Hermitian and $M$ real antisymmetric.

My argument would be that it might depend on the dimension $N$. If we count the distinct entries in each matrix: $\dim(A)=\frac{N}{2}(N+1)$, $\dim(B)=N^2$ whereas $\dim(M) = \frac{N}{2}(2N-1)$. So $M$ has less independent entries. On the other hand I would see no way to encounter any issue if you brute force and work out what $M=f(A,B)$ and viceversa $A=f(M,B), B=f(M,A)$ need to be.

Comment: Kitaev (https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2686) claims that any quadratic fermion hamiltonian can be written in Majorana form, so it's true in one direction at least. I think you are right that you can get the other direction just by brute force.

Comment: Doesn't the anticommutation relation of the $c_j$ constrain the number of entries of the $B$ to be less than $N^2$?

Comment: I would say so.

Comment: You should pay attention to the dimension question because coefficients can be complex

Comment: @BaptisteBermond so are you saying that I have them wrong and that they should match?

Comment: $B$ needs to be skew-symmetric.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian Yes, for example if you look into https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840794/what-is-dimension-over-mathbb-r-of-the-space-of-n-times-n-hermitian-matrice $dim(A) =N^2$

Comment: @BaptisteBermond I agree. However, does having the same number of parameters imply that the answer to my question is *yes*?

Comment: No but at least it doesn't imply directly that the answer is no ;-)